# Using MacOS as a VM and a legal copy

Tags: virtualization, mac-osx, mac

I'm interested on trying out using MacOs in Windows. My main machine is Windows 10. I can use either VMware or VirtualBox in the windows machine but I cannot get any source to get the Disc img for MacOs to start building my MacOs vm.

I know some people uses a real Mac machine extract the OS etc. Then they put it to a standard PC and become a hackintosh. I'm not interested in that. I just need a plain MacOs vm, Mojave or higher.

Any suggestion on how to do this in a legal way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. [macOS software license agreement](https://www.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macOS1014.pdf) only permits installing on Apple hardware. Even the virtual machine grants are limited to a "Mac Computer you own or control that is
already running the Apple Software".

Try it at an Apple store if you can, then buy a Mac.

After the return policy expires, well, that was a business expense that taught you what tools you like. Sell it or install Windows on it with Boot Camp.